# C# - can Generic with Return Type with Overloading?

Tags: c#, .net

I spent a lot of time searching, but there were many people who said I couldn't do it.
However, it may be possible in the latest C# version, and I think I may have read past posts, so I'm asking just in case

The intention of the example below is to have the same call structure, but handle different return types.

Since the generic type does not come in as a parameter, type inference cannot be made and must be explicitly declared.

I know that the following structure (template specialization) is possible in C++, but is there a way in C#?

There is also a way to make Foo an Interface and create a custom class that inherits JObject and Foo, but I do not want to use it if possible

C# version is currently using 6.0

```csharp
class ReturnType<T>
{
    List<T> result_set;
}
class Bar : Foo 
{
}

static ReturnType<TReturn> Execute<TReturn>()
    where TReturn : Foo
{
    //something about Foo Inherited class
    return ...;
}

static ReturnType<JObject> Execute<JObject>() 
{
    //something about JObject
    return ...;
}


Execute<Bar>();   <- call first function
Execute<JObject>();   <- call second function
```

Comment: Your method signatures are misaligned. The generic argument goes after the method name. In addition, the generic argument can't be _a type_ (`JObject`). Your first method signature would need to be `static ReturnType<TReturn> Execute<TReturn>()` you need to define the generic argument, and that definition must be after the method name.

Comment: Your second method signature is incorrect. `JObject` is a type, not a variable name for a generic argument. `static ReturnType<JObject> Execute()`. Is this similar to what you're looking for? https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZI9IYB

Comment: If you use 'static ReturnType<JObject> Execute()', it will be Execute(), not Execute<JObject>().

Comment: What you're asking for isn't possible in C#. The second method shouldn't (and can't) use generics - it's a fixed type. You could just have one method which used a generic argument and have an if statement to check the type of `TReturn` and change your logic that way, but you'd need to remove the generic constraint because you're allowing `TReturn` to be a `JObject`, and `JObject` doesn't implement/inherit `Foo`. You might have an X/Y problem here. What problem are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: I wanted to have the same calling syntax.
Execute<Bar>() clearly has a Bar type as a result, but I don't think the person who calling Execute() will be able to predict that a JObject will come out

Comment: From the answer just above, I understood that the structure I wanted was impossible